# Weekly notification pops up within a minute of setting the reminder

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to android and I'm presently working on Notifications.

I have 2 types of notifications to be displayed. one is a weekly reminder and the other is a monthly reminder.

Here's how I've set the weekly reminder:

```
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, currentTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY *7, pendingIntent);
```

and here's how I've set the monthly reminder:

```
long monthlyDuration = getDuration();
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, currentTime, monthlyDuration, pendingIntent);




private long getDuration(){
        // get todays date
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        // get current month
        int currentMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        // move month ahead
        currentMonth++;
        // check if has not exceeded threshold of december

        if(currentMonth > Calendar.DECEMBER){
            // alright, reset month to jan and forward year by 1 e.g fro 2013 to 2014
            currentMonth = Calendar.JANUARY;
            // Move year ahead as well
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)+1);
        }

        // reset calendar to next month
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, currentMonth);
        // get the maximum possible days in this month
        int maximumDay = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, maximumDay);
        long thenTime = cal.getTimeInMillis(); 



        return (thenTime); 

    }
```

Here's the notification code:

```
   int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "default");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = context.getString(R.string.channel_name);
            String description = context.getString(R.string.col_week_rem_description);
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        builder.setAutoCancel(false);
        builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
        builder.setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        builder.setContentText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.notification_text));

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_notification);

            int myColor =
                    context.getResources().getColor(R.color.notification_icon_bg);

            builder.setColor(myColor);

        }
        else {

            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        }

        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
//        builder.setOngoing(true);
//        builder.setNumber(100);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,builder.build());


    }
```

The problem I'm facing is, that the notification pops up within a minute or 2 from the time when the option to show the reminder is set. What I want to do is that when the user chooses a weekly reminder, he/she should receive the notification at the same time after 7 days. i.e. if I choose the weekly reminder today at 3'o clock. Then I should receive a notification at 3'o clock after 7 days from the day when the user chose the weekly reminder. The monthly reminder also works in the same way.

I've gone through a lot of threads here and elsewhere but couldn't fix the problem. Can anyone please help me fix the problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void setReminder(Context ctx) {

        Calendar setcalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        // setcalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 3);

        setcalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, //notification hr);
        setcalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, //notification min.);
        setcalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, //notification sec.);
        setcalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, //notification day);



        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, NotificationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);

        long timeMs = setcalendar.getTimeInMillis();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeMs, pendingIntent);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeMs, pendingIntent);
        } else {
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeMs, pendingIntent);
        }

        Log.e("", "setReminder: reminder has been set");
    }
```